# Pointer to function in C++ Doxygen-generated documentation

Tags: c++, pointers, doxygen

What does following line mean?

```
bool(*)(const GA_Attribute *, void *)   approve = NULL;
```

where `GA_Attribute` is custom class.

This line is passed to a function, so I can understand that if user doesn't pass anything then it defaults to `NULL`.

I do understand type conversion but I have no idea what `bool(*)` and `(const GA_Attribute *, void *)` are doing here?

**EDIT**:

Please see the function declaration [here](http://www.sidefx.com/docs/hdk/class_s_o_p___node.html#aa1c7a6ec597c9d48d201df103d732908)

**EDIT 02**:

Title is changed from:
**Pointer explicit type conversion and initialisation in C++**

Initially it looked like type conversion to me. Now I understand that it's  just Doxygen formatting issue.

Comment: That is a [function pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work) in C.

Comment: `R (*) (P)` is the type of a function pointer to a function that takes `P` as parameter and returns `R`. There is no type conversion ...

Comment: The above line is not valid C++ or C. The declaration of a function pointer would be `bool(*approve)(const GA_Attribute*, void*) = NULL`.

Comment: The above line is passed to the function like this: `int fillAttribNameMenu (PRM_Name * menu_entries, int max_menu_size, bool(*)(const GA_Attribute *, void *) approve = NULL, void * approve_data = NULL)`

Comment: That still [isn't valid C++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1758b9ccc13019f1).

Comment: please see [here](http://www.sidefx.com/docs/hdk/class_s_o_p___node.html#aa1c7a6ec597c9d48d201df103d732908)

Comment: A documentation site isn't obligated to present perfectly compileable code in explanations. The fact the site "says so" doesn't mean this is how valid code is written.

Comment: Aha, that's just weird doc formatting. The [actual declaration](http://www.sidefx.com/docs/hdk/_s_o_p___node_8h_source.html#l01307) uses the correct syntax. So yes, this is just a function pointer as other comments indicate.

Comment: @StoryTeller this' well reputed [3D simulation software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Houdini_(software))'s documentation and it just compiles fine.

Comment: You are missing the point. The documentation and the code need no be the same thing.

Comment: But documentation generates automatically by formatting in Doxygen. Correct me if I'm wrong, I'm not that experienced in C++!

Comment: @PradeepBarua The docs generate automatically, but Doxygen is turning a *correct* declaration into a *technically incorrect* declaration. It still conveys the right information to the reader, but the generated declaration in the documentation isn't valid C++.

Comment: Got it! So now this question and it's title doesn't make sense, right? Should it be here?

Comment: The title doesn't. The question makes sense *in the context of Doxygen-generated documentation.*